# How to move Vim's -- INSERT -- to another place of monitor

Tags: vim

I have an annoyance with Vim on my laptop - I can not see
`-- INSERT --`
line of my Vim installation because of my hands of the laptop keyboard. I want to see this word in the top line of my text interface, but now I have it on bottom. [image: I hope a screenshot of my Vim in fullscreen mode is enough convincing that I may not see this line because of my hands]

Answer (score 1):

The element where you see `-- INSERT --` is the `statusline` (`:help statusline` explains more).

`vim` can't move that around, so the only way forward is to ask your window manager to not extend windows to the bottom of the screen, where you can't see them.

**However**:

If you used `neovim` instead of `vim` (exactly the same UI), you could set the `winbar` option to something you like, for example the same value as the `statusline`.

`:set statusline` will show you the string that is set to.

`:set winbar=…`, replacing `…` with the value from above, if wanted modified, would be a viable solution to have the statusline both above and below the text.

Comment: Can I move it to the middle of the screen? For example, change `-- INSERT --` text to                       `--                         INSERT --`

Comment: Yep, you can add spacing to statusline